# Comments from mobile apps & Disqus

Tags: comments, mobile, disqus

I'm currently using Disqus in my WordPress Installation, and I am pretty happy with it. However, I'd like to extend my native mobile app (Windows Phone) to allow the users to post comments directly inside the app. 
I'm using a framework which supports WordPress comments for registered users out of the box, and I wouldn't want to rewrite the app to explicitly support Disqus. But as far as I know I can't combine both systems without problems, right?
I'm certainly not the only person with that problem, so what's your strategy? Should I switch to Jetpack comments? I don't want to loose social login options, at least on the normal homepage.

WordPress Version 3.6.1

[Disqus Comment System Version 2.74](http://wordpress.org/plugins/disqus-comment-system/)

http://disqus.com/

[Jetpack](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/)

Comment: Please always provide all needed sources to replicate the problem or given task. Those are for e.g. links to used plugins and your theme. Else it would be impossible to replicate your problem or fill the gaps in your code. Provide all this info directly as [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pre-release Windows Phone SDK right now for Disqus, and you might want to sign up and try that out: http://help.disqus.com/customer/portal/articles/1222036

Generally speaking it's not difficult to sync up discussion threads between a mobile app and a Wordpress site.